# How can i combine all the tokenized word to a sentence in a column?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-preprocessing

How can I combine all the tokenized words into a sentence in a column?

```
tokenized_word = ['really','smart','people']
```

in a `sentence = really smart people`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove_punctuation(txt):
  txt_nopunt = " ".join([c for c in txt if c not in string.punctuation])
  return txt_nopunt

data['tokenized_word'] = data['tokenized_word'].apply(lambda x: remove_punctuation(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard `join` operation in Python:

`sentence = ' '.join(tokenized_word)`

If you want to convert it to Pandas column, you can do it like this:

`df['col_name'] = sentence